# Finding the limit $\lim_{t\to ∞} \mathbb{E}[R_t]$ of an SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

I have the SDE

$$dR_t = (1 - \beta R_t)dt + \sigma dB_t$$

In this equation, $R_0 = r$ in which  $r > 0$

Can someone please help me find the $\lim_{t\to ∞} \mathbb{E}[R_t]$?

Thus far I have calculated the expectation:

From Itô's lemma
$$d(e^{\beta t}R_t)=\beta e^{\beta t}R_tdt+e^{\beta t}dR_t+\underbrace{d[{{e}^{\beta t}},{{R}_{t}}]}_{0}$$
$$d(e^{\beta t}R_t)=e^{\beta t}dt+\sigma e^{\beta t} dB_t$$
Then
$$e^{\beta t}R_t=R_0+\frac{1}{\beta}(e^{\beta t}-1)+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{\beta s}dB_s$$

$$R_t=R_0e^{-\beta t}+\frac{1}{\beta}(1-e^{-\beta t})+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\beta (t-s)}dB_s$$

$$\mathbb{E^Q}[R_t]=re^{-\beta t}+\frac{1}{\beta}(1-e^{-\beta t})$$

What do I do from here?

Comment: How is $R_t$ defined? Why do you define $X_t$ without any use for it?

Comment: Sorry I had mixed up a couple of variables. I have made the appropriate edits to the problem so that *R$_t$* is properly defined.

Comment: This exact question was asked recently on the site. It was already noted that the $e^{\beta t}R_t$ trick is not necessary, simply deduce from the SDE that $$R_t=R_0+\int_0^t(1-\beta R_s)ds+\text{martingale},$$ hence $$È(R_t)=E(R_0)+\int_0^t(1-\beta E(R_s))ds,$$ end of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\beta>0$, then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} E(R_t) &= \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left[R_0 e^{-\beta t} + \frac{1}{\beta} (1-e^{-\beta t}) \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\beta}.
\end{align*}